# Add change event to p:selectOneListbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm working on a component that populates a list of rights based on a list of users. When you click the name of a user, the other list should get populated.

sample code:

(.xhtml file)

```
    <h:form id="rolesRightsCustomizerForm">
        <!-- #{msgs.select_role} -->
        <p:panelGrid id="rolesRightsCustomizerPanel" columns="3">
            <p:selectOneListbox id="selectRoleList"
                value="#{cc.attributes.controller.rolesRightsCustomizer.selectedRole}"
                converter="entityConverter" immediate="true">
                <f:selectItems var="role"
                    value="#{cc.attributes.controller.rolesRightsCustomizer.roles}"
                    itemLabel="#{role.role_desc}" itemValue="#{role}" />
                <p:ajax event="change"
                    process="rolesRightsCustomizerForm:rolesRightsColumnsPicklist"
                    update="rolesRightsCustomizerForm:rolesRightsColumnsPicklist"
                    listener="#{cc.attributes.controller.rolesRightsCustomizer.reinit}" />
            </p:selectOneListbox>

            <p:pickList id="rolesRightsColumnsPicklist"
                render="#{cc.attributes.controller.rolesRightsCustomizer.selectedRole != null}"
                value="#{cc.attributes.controller.rolesRightsCustomizer.columns}"
                var="column" effect="none" itemLabel="#{column.column_description}"
                converter="entityConverter" itemValue="#{column}">
                <f:facet name="sourceCaption">#{msgs.hiddenColumnsList}</f:facet>
                <f:facet name="targetCaption">#{msgs.shownColumnsList}</f:facet>
            </p:pickList>
        </p:panelGrid>
```

RolesRightsCustomizer class:

```
public class RolesRightsCutomizer implements Serializable{
  private List<Role> roles;
  private Role selectedRole;
  private RoleService roleServ = new RoleService();
  private DualListModel<Column> columns;


...


  public DualListModel<Column> getColumnsState() {

    //Get all columns of the view and return the new list
    return new DualListModel<Column>(source, target);
  }

  public void reinit() {
    log.info("reinit method call");
    log.info("Reinitializing the user_rights object");
    user_rights = new UserRights(selectedRole);
    columns = getColumnsState();
    log.info("NEW ROLE:" + selectedRole.getRole_desc() + "\t" + columns.toString());
  }

//getters and setters 
... 

}
```

Why isn't the reinit() function fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `@this` to `process` attribute in `<p:ajax>`

```
process="@this rolesRightsCustomizerForm:rolesRightsColumnsPicklist"
```